# Why $\frac{1}{2}\ln |2x+7| + K = \ln|2x+7|^{1/2}+\ln k$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

My textbook jumps from:

$$\frac{1}{2}\ln |2x+7| + K$$

to:

$$ = \ln|2x+7|^{1/2}+\ln k = \ln k\sqrt{|2x+7|}$$

Why does the constant change from $K$ to $\ln k$?

Comment: They deliberately re-expressed $K$ as $\ln k$, in preparation for combining everything under one $\ln$

Comment: yeah but they're not equal. What's the logic? @JustinBenfield

Comment: Ah I just got it ... failed to give meaning to the $K$ going lowercase

Comment: Yes they made the substitution $K=\ln k$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the codomain of $\ln$ function is $\Bbb R$ then for $K\in\Bbb R$ there is $k>0$ such that $K=\ln k$.

Comment: yeah, but isnt $K \ne \ln k$

Comment: @EricJohnson - **note** that $K$ is just some constant, so we can find some **other** number, say $w$, such that $\ln w=K$. In your problem they choose to call this **other** number $k$ (i.e. little 'k' as opposed to the big 'K')